# Ucma 4.0 / 5.0 on NanoServer or Windows Server Core?

Tags: docker, containers, skype-for-business, ucma, nano-server

I want to use ucma API on windows container.But I want to know, can I host the API on nano server or windows server core?

I searched ucma documents but I didn't find any information about containers.
According to requirements, it seems to work only with Windows Server 2016 and Windows server 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to get a UCMA application to start/register and even accept a call running on a server core container, but it took some doing.  The runtime needs to be installed in the container image, which needed to be done manually.  You also need to provision the app using the container host's details, and get the cert into the container.

The place where it all breaks down though is with media-if your app needs to play/record prompts for calls, you can't do it from server core.  Container or not, the OS is missing the runtime for WMA, and from what I've found, it can't be installed.

For what it's worth, the SFB team doesn't even support UCMA on server core, let alone core on a container, so you're dealing with a couple of layers of "not supported" stuff.

Answer (score 1):

UCMA applications will work fine on Windows Server Core as long as your application doesn't have any UI.

Nano Server I'm not sure.

As far as I know, Nano Server only runs 64-bit applications.  UCMA application can run in 64 fine but what I don't know is what .net framework is supported on nano server.  If it supports the full .net framework, it may work.

I don't think you will know unless you try it yourself and see if it works or not.

Comment: Thanks for answer.I just wanted to know which platform is supporting ucma. According to your answer, I can run on server core. And I will try on nano server too as your mention.
Thank you so much again.